# How to save dataset in database according to my scenario?

Tags: c#, database, telerik, dataset, telerik-scheduler

I am working on my final year project I used telerik rad scheduler and em not able to save appointment data on appointment table I used this code in update button

```
tableAdapterManager1.AppointmentsTableAdapter.Update(this.schedulerData1DataSet.Appointments);
tableAdapterManager1.ResourcesTableAdapter.Update(this.schedulerData1DataSet.Resources);
tableAdapterManager1.AppointmentsResourcesTableAdapter.Update(this.schedulerData1DataSet.AppointmentsResources);
tableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(schedulerData1DataSet);
```

I save changes on dataset I have seen my dataset "visualizer dataset" where I see all changes are fine which I have made but in appointment table there is no changes which I made :( em very tensed plz help me em beginner in c# not a good concept on adapter plz explain carefully and tell me code as well where should I make changes to solve my problem

thankx regard shah;

Comment: Even after edit it's hardly readable.